# Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver in Serenity

Tags: selenium-webdriver, serenity-bdd, selenium-edgedriver

Serenity is unable to find the `msedgedriver` executable from the `serenity.properties` file. My properties file looks like this:

```
#webdriver.driver=chrome
#webdriver.chrome.driver = src/test/resources/webdriver/windows/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe

webdriver.driver=edge
webdriver.edge.driver = src/test/resources/webdriver/windows/edgedriver-win64/msedgedriver.exe

#webdriver.driver=firefox
#webdriver.geckodriver.driver = src/test/resources/webdriver/windows/firefoxdriver-win64/geckodriver.exe

...
```

When using `chromedriver` or `geckodriver`, Serenity has no issue finding their executables and instantiating the webdrivers as expected. The path to the `msedgedriver` is correct, and I've also tried absolute path with no luck.

My Edge Browser version is compatible with the downloaded msedgedriver version (123).

I cannot understand how Serenity is unable to successfully instantiate the driver, when I have correctly set the system property exactly like the other 2 drivers that work as expected.

Full error:

`Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver (The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.edge.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/MicrosoftWebDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=619687). See below for more details.`

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround!

For some reason, setting the system property in the serenity.properties file or serenity.conf will not work for msedgedriver.

But if your project is a gradle build, you can set the system property in there and it will work:

```
test {
    systemProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "src/test/resources/webdriver/windows/edgedriver-win64/msedgedriver.exe")
 }
```